# How to change class without affecting another class

Tags: javascript

I was wondering whether I'd be able to edit this class

```
<span class="chat-title">
    first title (I want to change)
</span>
```

without affecting this one

```
<span id="chat-subrooms-toggle" class="chat-title">
    Chat (I don't want to change) 
</span>
```

I want to use this sort of method though since it works well with the code

```
document.querySelector("chat-title").innerHTML = "title change";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `:not` pseudo-selector to filter that ID out. Also, you forgot a `.` when referencing the CSS class (CSS classes begin with `.` and IDs begin with `#`) here is what should work for you:

```
document.querySelector(".chat-title:not(#chat-subrooms-toggle)").innerHTML = "title change";
```

And here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KPrLg/) for you to look at which works

Comment: this doesn't seem to have any affect on the title (it doesn't change the text)

Comment: Works for me, see jsfiddle provided (I updated). Note `querySelector` doesn't work the same in all browsers, you might wanna look at alternate ways to do this.

Comment: i tried the jquery method but again it doesn't seem to work...  would `document.getElementByClassName("chat-title:not(#chat-subrooms-toggle)").innerHTML = "title change";` work?

Comment: Wait, I just noticed there isn't a period before the class. Could that be it? Your original question has this problem as well. Updated

Comment: Anyway in jQuery it should be `$('.chat-title:not(#chat-subrooms-toggle').html('title change');` or `$('.chat-title').not('#chat-subrooms-toggle').html('title change');`

Comment: i got it working now changed a few things in the original solution thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you can add another class to the first div .

```
<span class="chat-title to-change">
    first title (i want to change)
</span>
```

and leave this as it is :

```
<span id="chat-subrooms-toggle" class="chat-title">
    Chat (i don't want to change) 
</span>
```

and here js code :

```
document.querySelector("to-change").innerHTML = "title change";
```

goodluck